# How can I set the text color of an individual menu item in Kotlin?

Tags: android, menu, kotlin, menuitem

How can I set the text color of an individual menu item in Kotlin?

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            toolbar.title = "Home"
            item.actionview.SetColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.highlight))
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(homeFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with spannable string
Use these functions:

```
    fun getColoredSpannableString(s: String, color: Int): SpannableString {
        val str = SpannableString(s)
        str.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, s.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        return str
    }

    fun makeMenuItemColored(mi: MenuItem, color: Int) {
        mi.title = getColoredSpannableString(mi.title.toString(), color)
    }
```

and from your activity call:  
`makeMenuItemColored(mi, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))` 
where `mi` is your menu item and change the color to whatever you like.